# How can I fix my virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to OS X Mountain Lion and it killed most of my Python environment. I've reinstalled distribute 0.6.28 (`python distribute_setup.py install --prefix ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`) & pip 1.1 (`python setup.py install --prefix ~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`) from scratch. Then I installed `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwerapper` via `pip` without error, but the command `virtualenv ENVTEST` is failing as follows:

```
$ virtualenv ENVTEST
New python executable in TESTENV/bin/python
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/x/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools.................done.
Installing pip....
Complete output from command /Users/csh401/TESTENV/bin/python /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/easy_install /Users/x/Librar...ort/pip-1.0.2.tar.gz:
/Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/x/TESTENV/bin/easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1054, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 654, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1020, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/x/.virtualenvs/env1/bin/python -x /Users/x/.virtu...nv1/bin/easy_install /Users/x/Librar...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz failed with error code 2
```

My best guess is that it has to do with the fact that I was having trouble installing `distribute` and `pip` until I added the `--prefix` argument. But now while pip is working, it's not installing to the right location.

**UPDATE**

pip installed an older version of virtualenv. I ran `pip install -U virtualenv` and this ran without a hitch. Still getting an error, but a different error, now.

```
$ virtualenv -vvv TESTENV
Creating TESTENV/lib/python2.7
Symlinking Python bootstrap modules
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/config
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/os.py
  Ignoring built-in bootstrap module: posix
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
  Cannot import bootstrap module: nt
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/ntpath.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/fnmatch.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/locale.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/encodings
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/stat.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
  File TESTENV/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so already exists
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/types.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/re.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/sre.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
  File TESTENV/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlib.so already exists
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/abc.py
  Symlinking TESTENV/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
Creating TESTENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Writing TESTENV/lib/python2.7/site.py
Writing TESTENV/lib/python2.7/orig-prefix.txt
Writing TESTENV/lib/python2.7/no-global-site-packages.txt
Creating parent directories for TESTENV/include
Symlinking TESTENV/include/python2.7
Creating TESTENV/bin
New python executable in TESTENV/bin/python
Changed mode of TESTENV/bin/python to 0755
MacOSX Python framework detected
Symlinking TESTENV/.Python
Testing executable with TESTENV/bin/python -c "import sys;out=sys.stdout;getattr(out, "buffer", out).write(sys.prefix.encode("utf-8"))"
Got sys.prefix result: u'/Users/x/TESTENV'
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/x/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Creating TESTENV/lib/python2.7/distutils
Writing TESTENV/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py
Writing TESTENV/lib/python2.7/distutils/distutils.cfg
Using existing distribute egg: /Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/distribute-0.6.27.tar.gz
Installing distribute...
  Running command /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra... main(sys.argv[1:])
" -v --always-copy -U distribute
  Extracting in /var/folders/97/bds2slvx25s53xx1b_strvfs4xdq4b/T/tmpbqvjfq
  Now working in /var/folders/97/bds2slvx25s53xx1b_strvfs4xdq4b/T/tmpbqvjfq/distribute-0.6.27
  Installing Distribute
  running install
  Checking .pth file support in /Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
  /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python -E -c pass
  TEST FAILED: /Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
  error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

  You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
  on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
  installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
  the distutils default setting) was:

      /Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

  and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

      ''

  Here are some of your options for correcting the problem:

  * You can choose a different installation directory, i.e., one that is
    on PYTHONPATH or supports .pth files

  * You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH environment
    variable.  (It must then also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
    Python and want to use the package(s) you are installing.)

  * You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
    using one of the approaches described here:

    http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations

  Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
  Something went wrong during the installation.
  See the error message above.
...Installing distribute...done.
Installing existing pip-1.1.tar.gz distribution: /Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-1.1.tar.gz
Installing pip...
  Running command /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python -x /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/easy_install /Users/x/Librar...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz
  /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/x/TESTENV/bin/easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Complete output from command /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python -x /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/easy_install /Users/x/Librar...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz:
  /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/x/TESTENV/bin/easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
----------------------------------------
...Installing pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 942, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1054, in create_environment
    install_pip(py_executable, search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 654, in install_pip
    filter_stdout=_filter_setup)
  File "/Users/x/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1020, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/python -x /Users/x/TESTENV/bin/easy_install /Users/x/Librar...pport/pip-1.1.tar.gz failed with error code 2
```

So it looks like my PYTHONPATH is somehow blanked out in the environment virtualenv is trying to build. That should be easy to fix, right?

Comment: You say "killed my Python environment" but you don't explain that environment. Using vendor Python? Brew installed? Other?

Comment: Prior to upgrade, pip and virtualenv were working using the default system Python. I have a number of previously existing virtualenvs which work fine, but I cannot create any new virtualenvs. I don't remember how I installed pip and virtualenv previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with distutils. I deleted $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg and ran `sudo setup.py install` to get distribute in the right place, then `sudo setup virtualenv` which placed it into the appropriate site-packages directory for the MacPorts version of Python 2.7. Now I can run `virtualenv TestEnv` without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I face same Problem when setup the centos on VPS and my mac.

I found out the solution, If you not export some code after pip install it will be arise. The solution step is:

write command line:  which pip
                     show : '/usr/bin/pip' like this
then run this code on command line :  export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"

I hope that will also work for you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as I have not tested my thoughts.

The following code for a package, installs the `library at /x/lib/python2.x/site-packages` and the `scripts at /x/bin`

> python setup.py install --prefix /x

So you should not be doing `python setup.py install --prefix /x/lib/python2.x/site-packages`

Also try to see the scripts `pip` and `virtualenv` are they using the right python binary. The shebang in the scripts will tell you that. if not they may be using a different distribution.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'pip==1.1','console_scripts','pip'
__requires__ = 'pip==1.1'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

sys.exit(
   load_entry_point('pip==1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
)
```

The above script refers to a distribution with binaries located at `/usr/local/bin/python`.

On a system, you can have multiple distributions of python co-existing.